# equivalent shorthand

Tags: c#

What is the shorthand equivalent to the following snippent of code?

```
if (strValue == ""){
    throw new Exception("Mandatory 'strValue' parameter empty");
}
```

Comment: That's already pretty short. Anything shorter might make it unreadable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably as short as you can get it, barring removal of spaces and braces (and sacrificing readability in the process).

As for correctness... this might be better:

.NET 4.0:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue)){
    throw new ArgumentException("Mandatory 'strValue' parameter empty");
}
```

.NET < 4.0:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue)){
    throw new ArgumentException("Mandatory 'strValue' parameter empty");
}
```

Also note that it is bad practice to simply throw `Exception` - it is much better to select an appropriate exception class from the BCL if one exists, or a custom one if one doesn't. (thanks @djacobson)

Comment: Would probably be *even better* if you threw an `ArgumentException` rather than a base `Exception`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(strValue=="")throw new Exception("Mandatory 'strValue' parameter empty");
```

All you can do is remove the braces and spaces :)

Answer (score 4):

With a null check, which I think you want, and using ArgumentException:

```
ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(strValue, "strValue");

...

private void ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(string parameterValue, string parameterName)
{
    if String.IsNullorEmpty(parameterValue)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Mandatory 'strValue' parameter empty", 
                                    parameterName);
    }
}
```

Obviously only useful if you're doing this more than a few times.

Comment: Would make a great extension method, maybe throw the parameterValue parameter into an expression and pull the name back out to eliminate the need for the parameterName parameter.  (Your already throwing an exception, whats a tiny bit more overhead? :) )

Comment: @asawyer: Hmmm. An extension method doesn't feel right in this case. The action I'm taking is in the context of a method - now, if I could make an extension method on the *method* itself... which is getting close to Code Contracts, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Code Contracts.

You could also use string.IsNullOrWhitespace()

```
Contract.Requires(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue), "** fancy localized message here ***");
```

Comment: The reason why it's "shorter" is because you can conditionally remove it from release builds, retaining the check in the checked build.

Answer (score 1):

It's already short. Instead of doing strValue == "", I'd do String.Empty or String.NullOrEmpty, I can't remember which one is available in .NET

Answer (score 1):

Does not get much shorter, but if want less lines then:

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(strValue)) throw new Exception("Mandatory 'strValue' parameter empty");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much as short as you can get. I recommend using the IsNullOrEmpty String function for checking for an empty string. Also, it may be suitable to be more specific in your exception handling and throw an `ArgumentException`.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue)) { throw new ArgumentException("strValue must not be null or empty") };
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're trying to write more defensive code, you could use [Trace.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.assert.aspx)

```
Trace.Assert(strValue != "", "Mandatory 'strValue' parameter is not empty");
```

Or you could use the [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) library to encapsulate more complicated validation.